# RFC3339 - Date when no time is specified

Tags: time

If a date is specified in the format
**start=2021-04-05&end=2021-05-05**
does that mean that 2021-05-05 is excluded from the results?
and it's returning up to 11:59:59 on the 4th?

In an API I'm using, it *seems* to be behaving the same as
**start=2021-04-05T00:00:00Z&end=2021-05-05T00:00:00Z** when no time is specified.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- I think you are asking about the `full-date` format from [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), which is the same as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) extended date format: `YYYY-MM-DD`
- Neither specification says anything about inclusivity or exclusivity of date-only ranges.

  - ISO 8601 does talk a bit about ranges (they call them *intervals*), but they are defined as a pair of *instants*, not whole dates.
- The *typical* best practice (in my experience) would be to use a fully inclusive range for date-only values, or a half-open range for date-time values.  For example:

  ```
  [2021-04-05, 2021-05-05]
  [2021-04-05T00:00:00, 2021-04-06T00:00:00)
  ```

  However, this is not a hard rule.  The actual details would be highly specific to the particular API you are using and how the authors of that API designed it to function.
- A whole date like `2021-04-05` is not necessarily the same thing as `2021-04-05T00:00:00`.  In many cases, the reason to use a whole date is to *not* associate a time or a time zone at all.  But again, this is highly implementation specific.
- Nothing you've shown would imply that UTC (`Z`) is being used.  If that's how the API is behaving, that's another implementation detail of that API.

Comment: Thanks. I did wonder why I couldn't find a hard answer.
I have amended the title. In fact the documentation mentions 339 but links to 3339. So looks like their typo

Comment: No worries.  BTW, assuming the product is public, you'd get better results if you explained in your question which product and API you are using, with a link to the documentation.  Then you might get more specific answer about the design and intended use of that API, and maybe alternatives.  The best I can offer is a generic answer because you asked a generic question. :)

Comment: It's actually the Vanilla Forum API. And I found the page that goes into some detail about the dates. and it matches this answer with the ability to exclude and include, Though their final example confuses me. 

(2018-01-01,2019-01-01) // anything in 2018
which should be 
[2018-01-01,2019-01-01) to include the first date. Or am I completely misunderstanding. 

https://success.vanillaforums.com/kb/articles/45-date-filters

Comment: Yes, I would also think it would be `[2018-01-01,2019-01-01)`.  It could just be a docs typo, but you should check with them.